# How to hide some columns before exporting Telerek Gridview WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, telerik

I have a RadGridView(Telerik) that contains data. I want to hide some columns for exporting.

All solutions said that:

```
this.radGridView1.MasterTableView.FindByName("something").Display = false;
```

This code for asp.NET but I'm using WPF and there isn't any function like this.
Also doing

```
this.radGridView1.Columns["something"].IsVisible = false;
```

doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried using the column index?  this.RadGridView1.Columns[1].IsVisible = false; Are you using auto generated columns?

Comment: I  have tried but i could not reach my point.I don't use auto generate columns

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can be of help for you however, this is how I manage to hide columns in ASP:

```
protected void ExpExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridColumn col in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns)
    {
//here is where the columns get hidden
        if (col.UniqueName.Contains("notes") || (col.UniqueName.Contains("EditCommandColumn")) ||
            (col.UniqueName.Contains("column1")))
        {
            col.Display = false;
        }
        else
        {
            col.Display = true;
        }
    }
    foreach (GridFilteringItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.FilteringItem))

    item.Visible = false;
    RadGrid1.ExportSettings.FileName = "OffersData_"+DatetimeHelper.CETDateTimeNow();
    RadGrid1.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
    RadGrid1.ExportSettings.Excel.Format = Telerik.Web.UI.GridExcelExportFormat.ExcelML;
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.FindByUniqueName("chancesy").HeaderText = "Chances y [%]";
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.FindByUniqueName("chancesx").HeaderText = "Chances x [%]";
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.FindByUniqueName("valuey").HeaderText = "Value z [€]";
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.FindByUniqueName("valuex").HeaderText = "Value z [€]";
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.FindByUniqueName("marginy").HeaderText = "Margins y [%]";
    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.FindByUniqueName("marginx").HeaderText = "Margins x [%]";

    RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();

}
```

Comment: Yeah I know but in wpf there isn't MasterTableView so I can't deal with it :)